# needed a suggestion in redirecting old URLs to a new URL

Tags: http, redirect

Earlier i have installed my code in the main domain itself. for instance,

www.abcd.com/xyz/page.html

there are about 300 pages indexed by google with the old URL.

Now i have removed that code from the main domain and installed the code in Sub-Domain. So it make all the URLs indexed by Google and all the backlinks are pointing to the old URL.

Now i need to point all the old invalid URL to new Valid URL when Users clicks on the old URL.

Please suggest how to handle this.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I guess nobody is going to ask why this is tagged with all the languages in the world.

Comment: @Perception i was just about to ask that...

Comment: @Neal at least I was able to quickly navigate back to the 'real' Java questions!

Comment: C++ ∉ "all the languages in the world".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Apache, I suggest that you use `mod_rewrite` as it allows to send the HTTP status `301 Moved Permanently`, informing search engines that the contents of your website has been moved to a new location (rather than just deleted).

In a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first line enables URL "rewriting", the fancy term for redirections of all kind. The second line is decomposed like this:

- `RewriteRule` is the directive to match URLs and change the place they point to;
- `(.*)` is a regular expression matching any requested file path (without an initial slash)
- `http://newdomain.mysite.com/$1` is the place where you want to send your visitors, and `$1` is expanded to the previously matched path
- `[R=301,L]` tells Apache to send the `301 Moved Permanently` HTTP status code, and that it's the last `RewriteRule` that can match this request (it's useful only when you have multiple `RewriteRule`s but it doesn't hurt to have it anyways).

The next time crawlers visit your site, they will notice the HTTP status and update their links to your new address. You should have it set up as soon as possible before Google thinks your whole site went 404.

Comment: Thanks a lot... the old URL structure is like www.abcd.com/xyz/page.html... but the new URL structure is like subdomain.abcd.page.html... XYZ part in my old url was removed... in this case how to handle this... sorry for the trouble...

Comment: @user1050185, you'll probably want something along the lines of `RewriteRule xyz/(.*) http://newdomain.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache as your web server you can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) command. This is more a server job and not a programming job.

You can put the following in a `.htaccess` file or in the `vhost` container.

### mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xyz/page.html$ new-page.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

### mod_alias

```
Redirect permanent xyz/page.html http://domain.com/new-page.php
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

### PHP

You can use a `Location` header to perform a redirection:

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/new-page.php', true, 301);
```

### Java

```
public void HttpServletResponse.setHeader(String name, String value)
```

See: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch05_06.htm

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled by the server, preferably using an htacces redirect

Answer (score -1):

PHP:

```
header('Location: new.url.com');
```

Comment: This is what I've used in the past too, it just redirects as soon as the page loads.  Since there is little code, it loads and redirects quickly.

Comment: That's not good for SEO! You should also send the status code `301 Moved Permanently`.

Comment: @Neal, there is some possible nitpicking though. The `Location` header expects a full URL, starting with the protocol (even though it's been abused in such terrible ways that browsers will get it all the same). Also, when PHP (or Apache, I'm not sure) sees you send the `Location` header, it sets the HTTP status to `302 Found`, which doesn't tell anything about if the content was temporarily or permanently moved; for this reason, it's better to make the 301 explicit (`header("Location: http://newplace.com/$url", true, 301)` would do it).

Comment: @zneak you **can** use relative URLs in a header.

Comment: @Neal, it works but it isn't standard behavior. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html, section 14.30.